# What are the different sorting types allowed in Reddit's JSON API?

Tags: python, json, api, reddit

I came across a function that fetches the top images from reddit, with its API.

```
sr='pics'
sorting=''
url = r'http://www.reddit.com/r/{sr}/{top}.json'.format(sr=sr, top=sorting)
```

However I found that early on the original coder posted something like this:

```
#'sorting' is whether or not the sorting of the reddit should be customized or not,
# if it is: Allowed passing params/queries such as t=hour, week, month, year or all"""
```

I'm not sure about how to use these other 'sorting' commands or where I can find more on how to use them. I'm not even sure if I should look more about the 'sorting' as part of json/reddit/python notation.

What I'd like to do is to not only get the top images which are defined by sorting='', but the bottom images as well (sort other way around, if possible) through another query.

Comment: See [the official documentation](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_{sort}) for the list of options for sorting.

Comment: And there is always the [source code](https://github.com/reddit/reddit). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to a subreddit normally and click on top and then links from 'this week' the URL is

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/top/?sort=top&t=week

If I change top/ to top.json

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/top.json?sort=top&t=week

I get the JSON equivalent.
However, controversial links from the week URL is

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/controversial/?sort=controversial&t=week

which becomes

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/controversial.json?sort=controversial&t=week

So it does not appear that getting the bottom is possible from this test.

Like @Martijn commented. This is an reddit API issue and not a Python or JSON issue.

Comment: Alright thanks, yeah I just went over the issue and found this as well: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_{sort} I think you're right: getting the bottom might not be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

[image: hot, new, rising, controversial, top, wiki]

To stick with your url variable: `url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/{sr}/{top}.json'` Your method would need to assign one of the parameters in the above array, e.g. "rising"

You should set a default value so the method call doesn't fail w/o params passed, e.g.:

```
def get_data_from_reddit_api(sr="default subreddit value", top="hot")
  #url = ...
  #rest of reddit api request & subsequent parsing of the json feed
end
```